# Bulma css conflicting between two different products in same application on

Tags: css, reactjs, bulma

I have an application called abc.com, in this application, I have two products, product A and product B, both are in two different tabs but in same application, now the issue is, when we click on product A, the Bulma css library loads and when we click product B Bulma css library loads and it overrides the css styles of product B. How can I avoid this conflict? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would a CSS library load after a button click? Can you show the code of the button click handler?

Comment: Are the products supposed to have different CSS actually?